# Jasper Reports Exclude Column Headers in a Table?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, itext

I am using Jasper reports for a project that needs both PDF and CSV output and the majority of the data is the Detail section, within a table.  I know you can remove the pageHeader and columnHeader at the document level, but is it possible to remove, or only print once, the column headers within a table?  If not the CSV outputs,

```
User Type,Time,Username,Event,IP Address,Student Name,Student Number
Admin,6/6/11 8:09 PM,admin,Uploaded a report file.,0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,,
 ....[about 20 more lines of CSV then]....
User Type,Time,Username,Event,IP Address,Student Name,Student Number
```

This just looks very unprofessional and isn't very functional.  Like I said I know the page level headers can be removed with:

```
        jasperPrint.getPropertiesMap().setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.exclude.origin.band.1", "pageHeader");
        jasperPrint.getPropertiesMap().setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.exclude.origin.band.2", "pageFooter");
        jasperPrint.getPropertiesMap().setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.1", "columnHeader");
        jasperPrint.getPropertiesMap().setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.2", "pageFooter");
        jasperPrint.getPropertiesMap().setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.1", "columnHeader");
```

but I am looking for a solution to remove them on table for CSV output only, not PDF.  Is this possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Chuck

Answer (score 1):

Some useful properties to control report export for different formats.

> net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.1=title
>   net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.2=summary
>   net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.3=pageHeader
>   net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.4=pageFooter
>   net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.1=columnHeader
>   net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.collapse.row.span=false
>   net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns=true
>
> net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.csvSummary=summary
>   net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.1=title
>   net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.2=pageFooter
>   net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.1=columnHeader
>
> net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.1=title
>   net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.2=summary
>   net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.3=pageHeader
>   net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.4=pageFooter
>   net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.1=columnHeader
>   net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.collapse.row.span=false
>   net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns=true
>
> net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.using.images.to.align=false
>   net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.remove.emtpy.space.between.rows=true
>
> net.sf.jasperreports.export.ignore.page.margins=true

[Full reference](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html).

Comment: This solution worked for me. I really think it should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Column headers in the table component are meant to be repeated when the table overflows and cannot be hidden. To achieve what you want you could either:

move the contents of your columnHeader into the tableHeader so that only the table header prints once
or filter out the elements when performing a specific export by adding sets of properties like these:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.1" value="columnHeader"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.exclude.origin.keep.first.report.1" value="*"/>
```

More info on filtering elements at export time [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-can-i-suppress-page-headers-and-footers-when-exporting-xls) and [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.%7Bformat%7D.exclude.key.%7Bsuffix%7D).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should use different report definitions for each output. If not, then you could just recognise when you're printing to csv and only set those properties then.